# My app's icon becomes something else when installed from vs2010's installer

Tags: c#, installation

I am trying to create an installer via VS2010 for my app that is written in vs2012 using c#.I set an icon for my app in the properties menu of VS2012.I built an installer using vs2010 that makes some changes in the registry too(in a new subkey.No system changes).then I put my app's exe file in the application folder and created a shortcut for it in the desktop.the problem is that when I app is installed,the shortcut won't have a proper Icon,and the icon is like this:
[image]

I think it is worth mentioning that my app's icon is fine and If I create a new shortcut of it manually,the icon doesn't have a problem.so any idea about what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

- Select the setup project within Visual Studio.
- Click on the *File System Editor* icon above the solution explorer.
- Select the folder *User's desktop*.
- Select your shortcut on the right site.
- Right click your shortcut and select *Properties Window*.
- Double click on the *Icon* property within the property window.
- Click on the *Browse* button.
- Change the *File Type* at the bottom to *All files*.
- Double click on *Applications folder*.
- Double click on *Primary output from MyProject* (or where ever your main app resides).
- Select the desired icon and click *OK*.